# Page layout messing up when introducing new CSS over Bootstrap templates

Tags: css

So having a real issue. I'm trying to input a responsive newsletter form into my website, the site is using a bootstrap template.

I can successfully put the form in and in the right place but it completely messes up the rest of the layout on the site.

Is there anything specific I should be taking / removing / inserting into my CSS or index file.

Any help much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The CSS properties are applied to the document depending in the order in which you include the CSS files (if two class-definitions of same name occur in both the files) @Jamahi

Comment: This is a really vague question and it's hard to provide you with much useful insight if we can't see some code or an example.

Comment: Snippets are sometimes not enough as the context tends to be key. Can you setup a fiddle? (bootply.com/new)